# Installing Text::Fuzzy in cygwin 64 bit version

Tags: perl, cygwin

I am currently working to develop a code which helps me to find a closest string match for a given string from a list of strings. I came across a Perl module Text::Fuzzy which helps me to do that. But i am working on cygwin and a having hard time installing it properly by using cpan commands. So how do i properly install it?

Comment: This is a broad question. You will have to share the errors you are getting while installing the module. Looking at the source of module I found that it does not have any dependency. It's a XS based module which is relying on some C libraries.

Comment: Also the cpantesters result look good: http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Text-Fuzzy+0.24

Comment: @chankey Pathak Can't exec "make": No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2243.
  BKB/Text-Fuzzy-0.24.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 BKB/Text-Fuzzy-0.24.tar.gz                   : make NO (This is the error i am getting.........i can make neither head nor tail of what i am missing)

Comment: Which OS are you using? If it's UNIX based then check if `make` is installed in your system? If not then please do `apt-get install build-essential`.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/154418/where-do-i-get-make-for-cygwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Can't exec "make": No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Distribution.pm
```

This means that `make` is missing. You will have to install `make` to be able to install a Perl module.

Just do

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

Edit: Since you are using cygwin, please refer the link which [xxfelixxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866930/installing-textfuzzy-in-cygwin-64-bit-version/39867251#comment67021847_39866930) has suggested.

Comment: Thanks man......you pointed me in the right direction.....As morpheus said to neo "I can only show u the door. It is u have walk thru it" :p

Comment: @BrainsOfSteel: Heh. You may consider marking the answer the accepted if it fixes your problem or you can add your own answer and accept that. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work